# Integrated Version Control planned release

Tags: version-control

I came to know from a post that Integrated Version Control feature is going to be released into pilot in Winter or Spring '15 but there is no clue in summer '15 release either.

There is a idea posted for this on ideaexchange : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBKAA0.

Anyone has any info regarding its release and how to enroll for it?

Comment: Have you contacted your account executive?

Comment: No, I only have developer edition. I just wanted to know when its being released. Then I can approach to customers saying we can go for trial of this feature.

Comment: Since it's in pilot, paying clients should be able to get in it now. I'm personally not in that category long enough for it to matter, but I'd love to play with it.